# Wordpress pagination not working with search page

Tags: php, wp-query, search, location-search

In my search page, My query returns 11 pages with this search: `?q=2&s=chem`

But when I try to access another page other than the first, like `?q=2&s=chem&paged=2` for example, WordPress shows `error not found`.

Note: If I leave empty s variable in URL, I have no problem.

This is my `WP_Query` :

```
$args = array(

'number' => $number,
'offset' => $paged ? ($paged - 1) * $number : 0,
's' => $_GET['s'],
'meta_query' => array(
    'relation' => 'OR',
    [
        'key'          => 'comp_name',
        'value'        => $_GET['s'],
        'compare'      => 'LIKE'
    ]
),);
```

Someone knows how to fix this problem?

Comment: update your permanent links under settings

Comment: thank you, i check this but not working.

Comment: you checked and changed ? or just checked ? :)

Comment: change to "Custom Structure"

Comment: yeah , i have change and chek . but not working . you see this http://www.iranchembook.com/?q=2&s=&paged=3

Comment: and this http://www.iranchembook.com/?q=2&s=chem&paged=3 one URL working best. but two URL  show home page.

Comment: Why do you create a new query instead of using the main query? Use `pre_get_posts` if you need to alter the query parameters.

Comment: @Milo thank you. but this is not My main problem.

Comment: 404 is based on the main query, the query you run in the template is irrelevant.

Comment: @Milo ok but what can create a new search page for two arguments?

Comment: I must search for the two table with meta-box. one table is a new type of post and secondary table for users table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

by default, wordpress has it's own main query in search page, in your case you didn't changed the main query, and just create a custom query

paged is a reserved query variable which is used first by your main query, when your main query dosent have same results, you face a 404 error
you have 3 choices:

**1. change paged variable**

you can rename your page variable from paged to page or something else which is not used by wordpress by default

**2. override 404 page**

```
function override_404() 
{
    if ( is_search() && isset($_GET['s'])) {
        global $wp_query;
        $wp_query->is_404 = false;
    }
}
add_action('init', 'override_404');
```

**3. override main query ( best )**

```
function change_search_query() {
    if ( is_search() && isset($_GET['s'])) {
        $args = array();
        query_posts( $args );
    }
}
add_action('init', 'change_search_query');
```

Comment: I tried the same as shown above but not working still going on 404 page as soon as we click on next pagination link. For first time its ok.